# jqPlot Pie Renderer mixed data labels

Tags: jqplot, pie-chart, label

I am creating a custom pie chart using [jqPlot's PieRenderer](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-pieRenderer-js.html). My only problem is that I can either show the label or the percentage on the dataLabels. I want to do a mix and show both like `<label>\n<percentage>`. Explanation:

By setting `this.dataLabels = 'percent'`, I can do this:

[image]

By setting `this.dataLabels = 'label'`, I can do this:

[image]

I want to do this:

[image]

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/src/e8af8a37f0f14ea1e8c630ecfe6f1b1933794036/src/plugins/jqplot.pieRenderer.js?at=default#cl-463), `dataLabels` doesn't support rendering `label` together with `percent` at the same time.

I think you can easily create a list of labels using JavaScript and make sure you use `<br/>` instead of `\n` if you want to render 2 lines for each part.

Answer (score 0):

@sza's solution is tidier, so I will have to accept it. I wanted to post my own though, because it is easier and it may help someone.
What I did is, put two `pieCharts` on each other, where the first one is visible and has the percentage values and the second one has no fill and is invisible except for the labels.

My XHTML code:

```
<p:pieChart value="#{chartBean.pieModel}" legendPosition="" fill="true" showDataLabels="true"
    title="MyPieChart" style="width:100%; height:350px" sliceMargin="2"
    diameter="300" dataFormat="percent" shadow="false" extender="pieChartExtender"
    seriesColors="7eb75b,c2715e,6367c2,9b6ece,5cc2c1,c0c216" styleClass="mainPieChart" />
<p:pieChart value="#{chartBean.pieModel}" legendPosition="" fill="false" showDataLabels="true"
    title="MyPieChart" style="width:100%; height:350px" sliceMargin="2"
    diameter="300" dataFormat="label" shadow="false" extender="pieChartLabelExtender"
    seriesColors="7eb75b,c2715e,6367c2,9b6ece,5cc2c1,c0c216" styleClass="pieLabels" />
```

extender.js:

```
function pieChartExtender() {
    this.cfg.seriesDefaults.rendererOptions.dataLabelFormatString = '%#.2f%%';
    this.cfg.seriesDefaults.rendererOptions.dataLabelThreshold = 5;
    this.cfg.seriesDefaults.rendererOptions.dataLabelPositionFactor = 0.8;
    this.cfg.seriesDefaults.rendererOptions.startAngle = -90;

}
function pieChartLabelExtender() {
    this.cfg.seriesDefaults.rendererOptions.dataLabelThreshold = 5;
    this.cfg.seriesDefaults.rendererOptions.dataLabelPositionFactor = 0.8;
    this.cfg.seriesDefaults.rendererOptions.startAngle = -90;
}
```

CSS file:

```
.chartContainer {
    position:relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 10px;
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
}
.chartLegend {
    border: 1px solid #d7d7d8;
    margin: 40px 40px;
    width: 80%;
}
.pieExtra {
    position:absolute;
    left: 17px;
    top: 13.5px;
}
.pieLabels { position:absolute !important; }
.mainPieChart { position:absolute !important; }
.jqplot-title { display:none !important; }
.jqplot-grid-canvas { display:none !important; }
.jqplot-series-shadowCanvas { display:none !important; }
.mainPieChart .jqplot-event-canvas { z-index: 10 !important; }
.jqplot-data-label { color: #fff; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; }
.pieLabels .jqplot-data-label { margin-top: -9px !important; }
.mainPieChart .jqplot-data-label { margin-top: 8px !important; }
.pieLabels .jqplot-series-canvas { display:none !important; }
```

Notice that:

- both `pieCharts` (called `pieLabels` and `mainPieChart`) are absolutely positioned, in order to be placed on each other
- `jqplot-data-label` of `pieLabels` is placed 9px above and `jqplot-data-label` of `mainPieChart` is placed 8px below to create the label-percentage label
- `jqplot-series-canvas` for `pieLabels` is not displayed, in order to make it invisible.